# Current Month, Previous Month and YTD Count in card in Powerbi

Tags: powerbi, dax, measure

I need to create a card in which I have to show below numbers:

- Current month count
- previous month count
- ytd count (should start from last year 1st dec)

I have table in which have a column called DeliveryDate which has DATES (From 1st Dec'22 to Aug'23)

I also have column called productCount in same table

I have also created two drop down one from zone column (which has zone like .. east, south, north, west)

second drop down is created from DeliveryDate which has month( Jan, Feb, Mar and so on.

Current month count, previous month count and ytd count to be shown in a card.

---

Please see attached
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AYlS0.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tl6ka.png)

Comment: If you have a Calendar table, this is easy. If not, not so much. Current Month... MONTH(TODAY())
Previous Month CALCULATE([Total Sales], PREVIOUSMONTH('DimDate'[Date]))
YTD CALCULATE([Total sales], FILTER('DimDate', [Year]=MAX('DimDate'[Year]) && [MonthNumber]<=MAX('DimDate'[MonthNumber]))

Comment: Current Month, Previous Month and YTD Count should reflect basis Zone and Month Dropdown values selected.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, thanks for the data structure. That helps a lot.
Which part are you stuck on? The only vaguely complicated part I see is the end of fiscal year in November. The trick with that is to specify the last day of the fiscal year in the DATESYTD() function, like this:

```
YTD Count = CALCULATE([Delivery Count],
            DATESYTD( 'DimDate'[Date], "11/30")
```

"Selected Month Count" - if you select a month from the dropdown, your data will filter for just that month. BTW, you *really* need a Calendar table for this. Otherwise, when you go to do your YTD, only the dates with Counts will show up.

(If you're really new to DAX, Rob Collie's book is about the gentlest introduction to it.)

Your model would be something like this:

DimDate--FactTable--Region

Here's the DAX for your Calendar: (just create a table using DAX):

```
DimDate = ADDCOLUMNS(
        CALENDAR(
            MINX('Deliveries',[Delivery Date]),
            MAXX('Deliveries',[Delivery Date])
        ),
        "Year",YEAR([Date]),
        "MonthNo", MONTH([Date]),
        "DayOfYear", DAY([Date]),
        "DayNumberOfYear", DATEDIFF(DATE(YEAR([Date]),1,1),[Date],DAY) + 1
```

)